# Why is Distinct * not working but count(Distinct *) is working?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

There is a table (IN HIVE)
example - meanalytics.key2_master_ids
This table has 6 columns(cmpgn_id,offr_id,exec_id,creatv_id,cmpl_dt,mkt_cd) and possibly have duplicates(Duplicate rows)

Now These are the following queries that I ran

```
1)hc.sql("Select count(*) from meanalytics.key2_master_ids").show()
- +--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|  688919|
+--------+
```

```
2)hc.sql("Select count(distinct *) from meanalytics.key2_master_ids").show()

|count(DISTINCT cmpgn_id, offr_id, exec_id, creatv_id, cmpl_dt, mkt_cd)|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                589808|
```

From these two queries I infer that the table has duplicate rows.

Now I choose distinct rows using distinct * and see the count

```
3)hc.sql("Select count(*) from (Select distinct * from meanalytics.key2_master_ids)").show()
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|  688919|
+--------+
```

As you can see the count after using distinct *(688919) is the same normal count(*)(688919) but when I use count(distinct *)(589808) it is different.Can some one explain the results please?

EDIT 1)
Also tried explicitly selecting all the distinct values by providing all 6 column names, even after that the count is 688919 instead of 589808 which i got when i did count(distinct *)

```
hc.sql("Select count(*) from (Select distinct cmpgn_id,offr_id,exec_id,creatv_id,cmpl_dt,mkt_cd from meanalytics.key2_master_ids)").show()

+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|  688919|
+--------+
```

Comment: @KenWhite that's what they are doing though with `COUNT (DISTINCT *)`

Comment: Btw, not reproducible on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f0b97/4

Comment: Right, I see, your question is not about mysql really.

Comment: @zerkms: Yeah, I'm guessing this is going to be one of those MySQL things that bites me in the backside. Really wish they would do things that make sense. :-) Oh, wait - it's even worse. It's not even MySQL.

Comment: @KenWhite indeed, I even answered with "it's not a valid syntax" just to go to the documentation and to find I was wrong as well :shrug:

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT *)` is a syntax error in MySQL 5.6, 5.7, 8.0. I wonder if hive is substituting the column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that `COUNT(*)` is treated differently to `COUNT(expr)` in SQL. From the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

> COUNT(*) is somewhat different in that it returns a count of the
>   number of rows retrieved, **whether or not they contain NULL values.**

while `COUNT(DISTINCT expr)`

> Returns a count of the number of rows **with different non-NULL expr values.**

So if you have rows with `NULL` values, `COUNT(*)` will return all rows, as will `COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * ...)` (since `SELECT DISTINCT *` treats rows with `NULL` values as different from those with non-NULL values), but `COUNT(DISTINCT expr)` will count *only* rows with non-NULL values, hence giving a lower result.

The [hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)) shows that it behaves the same way.

See this [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53ac437fd47b322236cb258800aff2be) to see this in operation with a table with some rows with `NULL` values.

Note that `COUNT(DISTINCT *)` is not legal syntax in any version of MySQL (at least from 5.5 onwards). That may be a hive extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, in that case, how can I make other table from this table without any null rows?

Comment: @JayBhanushali you could try an `INSERT ... SELECT` query into a new table with a `WHERE` condition that excluded any rows which had `NULL` column values i.e. `cmpgn_id IS NOT NULL AND offr_id IS NOT NULL AND ...`

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is not a special case in mysql: it's a standard ANSI SQL syntax with mysql just implementing it as-is

Comment: @zerkms I was referring to the fact that MySQL treats `COUNT(*)` differently to `COUNT(expr)`; but you're right, the wording is confusing as that is standard behaviour. I have edited. I'm happy for you to edit if you think the wording can be further improved.